# What is proper type for React's children as function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, children

I'm passing a children as a function, returning `React.ReactNode` into Provider HOC like follows:

```js
<Provider variables={{ id: "qwerty" }}>
  {data => (
    <ExampleComponent data={data} />
  )}
</Provider>
```

Here's a provider component example code:

```js
type Props = {
  id: string;
  children: any; // What type should be put here?
};

const Provider: React.SFC<Props> = ({ id, children }) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery<req, reqVariables>(query, {
    variables: { id }
  });

  if (loading) return "Loading...";
  if (error) return "Error";
  if (!data) return "No data";

  return children(data);
}
```

If I'm not specifying any type for `children`, so leaving it to default to `React.ReactNode`, then line `return children(data);` shows an error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement ReactElement Component)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal' has no compatible call signatures.

If I'm specifying children explicitly in `type Props` as `any`, everything works great, but it's **Wrong** from a Typescript and types perspective.

What is a proper type to be put for `props.children`, when a function returning `React.ReactNode` is passed instead of `React.ReactNode` itself, so Typescript would accept it as a valid "Render function" and will allow calling `children` like function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the children type to be a function which returns a ReactNode

```
type Props = {
  id: string,
  children: (props: InjectedCounterProps) => React.ReactNode
};
```

Comment: could you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74013214/add-types-for-react-js-children-as-a-function

Answer (score -1):

`JSX.Element` can also be the type, in case the children being 'DOM element'.