# Add types for React js children as a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my react js application i have this code:

```
interface Interface<T> {
    submit: T,
    children: (ctx: { test: string, info: string }) => React.ReactNode | ReactElement;
}


const Test =<T, > ({submit, children}: React.PropsWithChildren<Interface<T>>) => {
    
    return (
        <div>
            {children({test: '123', info: '3'})}
        </div>
    )
}

const Show = () => {
    return(
        <Test>
            {(ctx) => {
                return <p>{ctx.test}</p>
            }}
        </Test>
    )
}
```

Adding these types i get some ts issues in this block:

```
 <Test>
  {(ctx) => {
    return <p>{ctx.test}</p>
  }}
</Test>
```

I get the next message from typescript:

```
TS2322: Type '(ctx: { test: string; info: string; }) => Element' is not assignable to type '((ctx: { test: string; info: string; }) => ReactNode | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>) & ReactNode'.   Type '(ctx: { test: string; info: string; }) => Element' is not assignable to type '((ctx: { test: string; info: string; }) => ReactNode | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>) & string'.     Type '(ctx: { test: string; info: string; }) => Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Why i get these message and how to solve it?

Comment: Can't reproduce it, works fine for me. Also, I'm pretty sure that `ReactElement` is a part of `ReactNode`